# Several system libraries missing in a VS Express install

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

I am having a problem I am trying to troubleshoot.  I developed a website in VS 2013, and am trying to set the website up for continuous integration on a server using teamcity.

I have already tested teamcity on my computer, and have it compiling perfectly using a VS2013 install.

On the server, I have everything working...except for the compilation.  In order to compile the website, I installed VS Express on the server.  The problem is, a new error is appearing on the server:

System.Net.Http.Formatting and

System.Web.Http

...are both missing.

Are they missing because of some error? Because I am using VSExpress instead of VS2013?

The actual error is:

> Security\ApiAuthentication.cs(7, 23): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Formatting' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Net.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Security\ApiAuthentication.cs(12, 18): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Security\ApiAuthentication.cs(21, 49): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Security\ApiAuthentication.cs(32, 48): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpActionContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you sure you have all the right .NET frameworks installed on the server? The framework libraries are separate from the Studio installation and installing a different studio version should not affect the libraries installed.

Comment: .NET 4.5 or higher is already installed

Comment: Do you have any NuGet package dependencies at all, namely [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/)?

Comment: ok, yes...but i have lots of nuget package dependencies, and this is the only compiler error.  Also, it compiles on teamcity on my local pc

Comment: Sorry I realised I was being a donut when I saw you said you had problems compiling.  See my updated comment.  Also, would you be able to post the full error stack off TeamCity?

Comment: lol, donut :)  yeah, totally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got VS Community 2013 on my local, in the base install the `System.Net.Http` namespace exists but `System.Net.Http.Formatting` does not.  This is the same with `System.Web` vs `System.Web.Http`.

On installing the [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/) NuGet package both appeared as expected and could be referenced.

Have you tried adding a [NuGet Restore](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/NuGet) step to your TeamCity build before compiling?  It's strange mind that these are the only errors you are seeing if there's been no NuGet restore in place.  Maybe a build order issue / red herring?